# SignalR Persistent connection starts timing out "poll" requests from clients and does not recover after restart

Tags: c#, mono, signalr

I have a weird problem with SignalR persistent connection. It runs within a mono-service written on c# and uses long polling transport. The application runs on a Ubuntu VM inside KVM. The communication between the application and HTML/js clients is mostly normal, but at some point for some reason every newly created connection behaves the following way : the connection is established and OnConnected method gets called, however, when client issues "poll" request, it times out. In 100% cases when the application enters this state, restarting it does not help : "poll" requests from clients still get timed out. The only thing that helps out is rebooting the entire VM. Is there anyone, who has ever experienced something like that? Does SignalR persist any connection data to the filesystem, which could be a reason why, after the application is restarted, it still times out long polling requests ?

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me! The problem had to do with database access which was happening during authorization of SignalR connection. The DB access layer was poorly designed, and the DB would become locked from time to time. The authentication procedure would then wait for DB lock to be released and eventually - time out. As a piece of advice for everyone reading this anecdote : in PersistentConnection case be sure that no IO-heavy stuff is happening inside AuthorizeRequest method! Or if you cannot avoid that, it should be very carefully designed, or else you are asking for timeouts.